# Solving DDE in Matlab using matrix form

Tags: dynamical-systems, delay-differential-equations

I am a beginner in learning DDE and i am trying to understand how to use matrix notation to simulate basic systems of the specific form below:
Let us assume a directed network with three nodes

$$\dot{y_{1}} = a_{11}y_{1} + a_{12}y_{2}(t-\tau_{12}) + a_{13}y_{3}(t-\tau_{13})$$

$$\dot{y_{2}} = a_{21}y_{1}(t-\tau_{21}) + a_{22}y_{2} + a_{23}y_{3}(t-\tau_{23})$$

$$\dot{y_{3}} = a_{31}y_{1}(t-\tau_{31}) + a_{32}y_{2}(t-\tau_{32}) + a_{33}y_{3}$$

The direct. way to code in Matlab for the above, is:

```
tau = [1.0 0.5 1.5];
tf = 10;
sol = dde23(@dde,tau,@history,[0 tf]);

t = linspace(0,tf,200);
y = deval(sol,t);

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(t,y)
grid on;

function dydt = dde(t,y,yd)

a11 = -1;a12 = 2; a13 = 1;
a21 = 2; a22 = -1;a23 = 1;
a31 = 1; a32 = 1; a33 = -1;
 
dydt = [a11*y(1)    + a12*yd(2,1) + a13*yd(3,2)
        a21*yd(1,1) + a22*y(2)    + a23*yd(3,3)
        a31*yd(1,2) + a32*yd(2,3) + a33*y(3)];

end

function y = history(t)

y = [1;0;-1];

end
```

the result is this:
[image: result with the direct implementation]

But for a n by n system, the process should be somehow automatized to produce the above $n(n-1)/2$ matrices plus the first one which is the diagonal:

$$\begin{multline}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{y_{1}}\\ 
\dot{y_{2}}\\ 
\dot{y_{3}}\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & a_{22} & 0 \\ 
 0& 0  & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\ 
y_{2}\\ 
y_{3}\\ 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_{12} & 0\\ 
a_{21} & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0& 0  & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}(t-\tau _{1})\\ 
y_{2}(t-\tau _{1})\\ 
y_{3}(t-\tau _{1})\\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
\\ + \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & a_{13}\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
a_{31} & 0  & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}(t-\tau _{2})\\ 
y_{2}(t-\tau _{2})\\ 
y_{3}(t-\tau _{2})\\ 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & a_{23} \\ 
0 & a_{32} & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}(t-\tau _{3})\\ 
y_{2}(t-\tau _{3})\\ 
y_{3}(t-\tau _{3})\\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{multline}$$

The code for the general case, applied in the same 3 by 3 is the following:

```
tau = [1.0 0.5 1.5];
tf = 10;
a11 = -1;a12 = 2; a13 = 1;
a21 = 2; a22 = -1;a23 = 1;
a31 = 1; a32 = 1; a33 = -1;

A = [a11 a12 a13;
     a21 a22 a23;
     a31 a32 a33];

sol = dde23(@(t,y,z)(dde(t,y,z,A)),tau,@(t,y)(history(t,A)),[0 tf],A);

t = linspace(0,tf,200);
y = deval(sol,t);

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(t,y)
grid on;

function dydt = dde(t,y,yd,A)

 n = length(A);
 
 A0 = diag(diag(A));
 m = n*(n-1)/2;
 P = zeros(n,n*m);
 k = 0;
 for i = 1:n
     for j = 1:n
         if j>i
             P(i,j+n*k) = A(i,j);
             P(j,i+n*k) = A(i,j);
             k = k+1;
         end
     end
 end
 
for c = 0:m-1
    
    dydt = A0*y + P(:,n*c+1:(c+1)*n)*yd(:,c+1);

end

end

function y = history(t,A)

y = [1;0;-1];

end
```

[image: result with the general case]

Comment: This looks good. One point that has to be handled carefully is the order of the delays between the different implementations. Can you give the code implementing the matrix system? It should be something like `A0*y+A1*yd(:,1)+A2*yd(:,2)+A3*yd(:,3)`.

Comment: Yes, I can! Please, mind the following: The problem is about the general case where i have to calculate the above for an n by n. So, the matrix system cannot be manually introduced within the function. The code I will add above, is still for a 3 by 3 but, I am trying to automate the process, and I am obviously failing- don't know what I mess up.

Comment: You can combine `for j=1:n if j>i` to `for j=(i+1):n`. Is it ensured that the reference solution gets a matching delay sequence?

Comment: I will reform the post with the codes and the graphs I receive

Comment: In this case the matrix approach might also not be the most efficient. It should be simpler and slightly faster to build `dydt` starting from `dydt=diag(A).*y` in a single double loop, instead of constructing `P`.

Comment: i understand. The code is far from being optimal. At the moment it might have the basic structure. Yet this structure has mistakes, which as many times as i came back to find, I only managed to re-write the same parts of code. Do you think that creating P might be erroneous besides suboptimal?

Comment: No, I did not see anything wrong. The question now looks solid and complete.

Comment: `sol = dde23(@(t,y,z)(dde(t,y,z,A)),tau,@(t,y)(history(t,A)),[0 tf],A);` is suspicious. `A` is a matrix, not an option structure generated with `odeset` to be put in the last place. It does serve no role there, should be removed. The `history` argument should only depend on `t`, that is, should start with `@(t)`. Too many arguments on the argument stack should not be problematic, the unused ones should be ignored. But who knows what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120874/discussion-between-alex-kps-bdc-and-lutz-lehmann).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious once you have found it, but at a superficial glance seems to have all the correct parts:

```
for c = 0:m-1 
    dydt = A0*y + P(:,n*c+1:(c+1)*n)*yd(:,c+1);
end
```

does not what you intended it to do. It should be

```
dydt = A0*y;
for c = 0:m-1 
    dydt = dydt + P(:,n*c+1:(c+1)*n)*yd(:,c+1);
end
```